# “No source available 0x” when debugging Linux kernel with Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, linux-kernel, eclipse-cdt

This is my first post to stackoverflow so apologise for any error :). I'm trying to debug a Linux Kernel using Eclipse/CDT by following the information provideed in multiple websites. However, everytime I try to debug the kernel I get a “No source available 0x....." message. (see the attached screenshot).

1. I run the linux kernel with a qemu virtualmachine "qemu -s -S -kernel bzImage ..."
2. I try to run the debug from Eclipse/CDT. For that, I configured a "C/C++ Attach to Application" debug. The application is the vmlinux file. The remote configuration of type gdbserver is configured as localhost:1234.

Altough I can't debug with Eclipse/CDT, I can debug the kernel with gdb CLI:

```
# gdb vmlinux
> remote target localhost:1234
> cont
```

Information about versions:

- Linux Mint 17 KDE
- Eclipse 4.4.1
- CDT 8.5.0
- qemu 2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.9
- gcc 4.8.2-1ubuntu6
- gdb 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2

Comment: Check whether you have enabled `CONFIG_KGDB` when build the linux kernel image

Comment: Yes it is enabled, according to my .config -> CONFIG_KGDB=y

Comment: the source files actually have to be available, where GDB will see them and the many object files, when compiled, need to be available and compiled (on gcc) with the -gdb3 parameter

Comment: the kernel source available are available in kernel/* and the object files under kernel/build/*; whereas kernel/* is the main folder of the Eclipse/CDT project. In the "Debug configurations" for debugging the kernel, there is a "Source" tab that already includes all the kernel/* files.

Answer (score 0):

A "C/C++ Attach to Application" debug configuration is not appropriate for this setup. You could use a "C/C++ Remote Application" configuration instead, with the manual remote debugging launcher:

- Open the Debug Configurations window in Eclipse and create a new a "C/C++ Remote Application" configuration
- At the bottom section of the window there is the indication of which launcher is being used: if you see anything other than the manual remote debugging launcher, click on "Select other..." and in the launcher selection window select "GDB (DSF) Manual Remote Debugging Launcher"
- In the Main tab of the debug configuration, in the Project field enter the Eclipse project where you have your Linux kernel, and in the C/C++ Application field enter your vmlinux file
- In the Debugger tab, under Debugger Options, select the Connection tab, then select TCP as connection type, write "localhost" in the host address field, and write "1234" in the port number field
- Possibly adjust the source lookup path in the Source tab
- Start QEMU with the usual "-s -S" options
- Now you should be able to start your debug session in Eclipse, with working symbol resolution and source lookup